# How to build Vue for traditional website (Jquery replacement)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I’m now looking into using Vue in an existing project as a replacement for jquery. I followed The Vue getting started guidelines and was able to recreate all functionality using vue. I created multiple single file component (.vue files) and use http-vue-loader to load them in my existing templates:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/http-vue-loader"></script>
<script>
        new window.Vue({
                el: '#app',
                components: {
                        'user-button': window.httpVueLoader('components/UserButton.vue'),
                        'like-button': window.httpVueLoader('components/LikeButton.vue'),
                        ... 
                },
        })
</script>
```

This works fine, I can now simply include
`<user-button></user-button>`
in the template, which renders the user button as expected.

I’m now looking into optimising my code, but I’m unable to find any information on how to proceed. Can I use this code in production and use http-vue-loader to import the components, or is there a way to build the code using vue-cli or webpack? I’m only using vue to add additional features to the website. The main content is generated server side. The Vue components need to be added to this content.

I tried adding the components to a sample project created using vue-cli, and building the scripts. This works fine, however I cannot use the scripts on my website. Embedding the scripts causes all existing content in the in=“app” container to be replaced.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I should proceed?

Comment: For small and existing project, i would recommend you to use vue CDN rather than webpack. Otherwise you would have create the whole website from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all what 'optimization' are you talking about? If everything works correctly I don't understand what is your question about.

About building with vue-cli, if your application already uses id `app` somewhere, you can simply configure vue to render it's contents into div with any other id. Just open `index.js` and specify your custom id in `$mount` function.

Comment: I started learning Vue by building a simple application. I build the scripts using vue-cli, resulting in optimized and chunked js files. In my current setup I’m simply loading the vue files I wrote and I wonder if this is the correct way to do this, or if there is a way to optimize this similar to what vue-cli build does with the code I wrote.

Comment: If you are using Vue as a replacement of JQuery I guess there are not a lot of code and it will work fast anyways(currently Vue is faster than any web framework), so there's no need in optimization.

Comment: Anyways to minify code you will need some kind of bundler, webpack or rollup will do, you can dig into the vue deployment docs to find more info about configuring them: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include (but this way you will be forced to build code every time you make changes, so I don't think that it is a good fit for simple vue aplication)

Comment: Awesome, I guess I will keep the code as it is now. Thanks for the explanation!